# Pi Zero as HID Device - no capital letters

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb, hid

I'm currently trying to emulate a keyboard with my pi zero w following several guidelines e.g., https://www.rmedgar.com/blog/using-rpi-zero-as-keyboard-setup-and-device-definition (all 3 parts) or this https://randomnerdtutorials.com/raspberry-pi-zero-usb-keyboard-hid/.

It seems to work but I can only make it type lower-case characters and I have no idea why. So e.g., with this code line (taken from the rmedgar guide)

```
write_report(chr(32)+NULL_CHAR+chr(11)+NULL_CHAR*5)
```

it just types a lower case "h" - so it seems that chr(32) is ignored - it is supposed to be SHIFT. I tried to trace the scancod of SHIFT with "showkeys -s" which is showing me 0x2a (push) and 0xaa (release). Then I replaced the 32 in above code with 42 (0x2a in dec) but that changes nothing.

I'm working on an old Thinkpad x230, can it be that the scancodes for shift are different?

Any other points that I'm missing?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Are you using the corrected script as posted in the user comment at the bottom of your second link? The HID report descriptor should be:
`echo -ne \\x05\\x01\\x09\\x06\\xa1\\x01\\x05\\x07\\x19\\xe0\\x29\\xe7\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x01\\x75\\x01\\x95\\x08\\x81\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x08\\x81\\x03\\x95\\x05\\x75\\x01\\x05\\x08\\x19\\x01\\x29\\x05\\x91\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x03\\x91\\x03\\x95\\x06\\x75\\x08\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x65\\x05\\x07\\x19\\x00\\x29\\x65\\x81\\x00\\xc0 > functions/hid.usb0/report_desc`

Comment: Oh my .... you are right. I was using the report descriptor from the first link which seems to be somehow incorrect (did not do a diff for now). Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No worries. I just checked the report descriptor from the first link and it contains an invalid definition of the modifier keys: `\\x1A\\x24\\x02\\x2A\\x31\\x02`. That should be replaced by `\\x19\\xe0\\x29\\xe7` as shown in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as pointed out by aja - I was using the wrong descriptor, it should be

```
echo -ne \\x05\\x01\\x09\\x06\\xa1\\x01\\x05\\x07\\x19\\xe0\\x29\\xe7\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x01\\x75\\x01\\x95\\x08\\x81\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x08\\x81\\x03\\x95\\x05\\x75\\x01\\x05\\x08\\x19\\x01\\x29\\x05\\x91\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x03\\x91\\x03\\x95\\x06\\x75\\x08\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x65\\x05\\x07\\x19\\x00\\x29\\x65\\x81\\x00\\xc0 > functions/hid.usb0/report_desc
```

The full script to enable the HID device on a raspberry pi zero therefore looks like this (mostly copied from the links mentioned in my first question).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create gadget
mkdir /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/mykeyboard
cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/mykeyboard

# Add basic information
echo 0x0100 > bcdDevice # Version 1.0.0
echo 0x0200 > bcdUSB # USB 2.0
echo 0x00 > bDeviceClass
echo 0x00 > bDeviceProtocol
echo 0x00 > bDeviceSubClass
echo 0x08 > bMaxPacketSize0
echo 0x0104 > idProduct # Multifunction Composite Gadget
echo 0x1d6b > idVendor # Linux Foundation

# Create English locale
mkdir strings/0x409

echo "My manufacturer" > strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo "My virtual keyboard" > strings/0x409/product
echo "0123456789" > strings/0x409/serialnumber

# Create HID function
mkdir functions/hid.usb0

echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/protocol
echo 8 > functions/hid.usb0/report_length # 8-byte reports
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/subclass
echo -ne \\x05\\x01\\x09\\x06\\xa1\\x01\\x05\\x07\\x19\\xe0\\x29\\xe7\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x01\\x75\\x01\\x95\\x08\\x81\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x08\\x81\\x03\\x95\\x05\\x75\\x01\\x05\\x08\\x19\\x01\\x29\\x05\\x91\\x02\\x95\\x01\\x75\\x03\\x91\\x03\\x95\\x06\\x75\\x08\\x15\\x00\\x25\\x65\\x05\\x07\\x19\\x00\\x29\\x65\\x81\\x00\\xc0 > functions/hid.usb0/report_desc

# Create configuration
mkdir configs/c.1
mkdir configs/c.1/strings/0x409

echo 0x80 > configs/c.1/bmAttributes
echo 200 > configs/c.1/MaxPower # 200 mA
echo "Example configuration" > configs/c.1/strings/0x409/configuration

# Link HID function to configuration
ln -s functions/hid.usb0 configs/c.1

#Sleep for 10 seconds
sleep 10

# Enable gadget
ls /sys/class/udc > UDC
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're sending an HID report with a capital letter in it, you need to make sure the modifier bit for the Shift key is set to 1, just like on a real keyboard where you type capital letters by first pressing Shift.  It's usually represented as a single bit at a fixed location in the report, not an 8-bit code.  I don't know the details of the API you are using, but you should search its documentation for keywords like "modifier", "shift", "ctrl", and "alt".